# Variational vs deterministic autoencoder

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

I tried to use VAE and DAE to train with MNIST dataset and see their performance. It turns out VAE has a greater loss but generates better sample images. Why does it happen?

Comment: I suppose this could happen for a number of reasons: difficulties in setting the learning rate, batch sizes, local minima, poor initialisation etc. Please post more information about how you conduct the experiments. Perhaps it's a good idea to experiment with out-of-the-box implementations. Also: there is no reason why a variational autoencoder should always outperform a deterministic autoencoder, see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.12436)